# Separate each alphabet by using preg_match PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

i know that this is a beginner level question, but i am stuck here and  i need help.

i want to store each alphabet in an array. (Only Alphabets not integers)

let me show you the previous code that i am using

```
$str = "ab c45 d123ef";
preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar);
```

its output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] =>  
            [3] => c
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
            [6] =>  
            [7] => d
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 2
            [10] => 3
            [11] => e
            [12] => f
        )

)
```

But it also separate integers... what i have to change in the preg_match expression, i want this output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] =>  
            [3] => c
            [4] => 45
            [5] =>  
            [6] => d
            [7] => 123
            [8] => e
            [9] => f
        )

)
```

Comment: Spaces aren't alphabetic, why are you matching them?

Comment: i also want to separate spaces... But if there is any integer it should not separate.. Is this possible..? :(

Comment: `preg_match_all('/\d+|./us', $str, $ar);`

Comment: Do you also want to keep punctuation? `.` matches everything.

Comment: Why the space after 45 is in a separate item in your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/[\d.]+|./us', $str, $ar);
```

`[\d.]` matches a digit or decimal point, the `+` quantifier after it matches a sequence of them.

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] =>  
            [3] => c
            [4] => 45
            [5] =>  
            [6] => d
            [7] => 123
            [8] => e
            [9] => f
        )

)
```

Comment: 1st of all Thanks, That's Great, it's working, but only a little problem left if you can help me, if i use 45.125 it also separate it e-g: "45" "." "125", is it possible to make it in sequence.. And Thanks Again..

Comment: See the updated answer. I think it should have been obvious how to add that, if you know the basics of regexp.

Answer (score 1):

A way with preg_split:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?=\pL)|(?<=\pL)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

You obtain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] =>  
    [3] => c
    [4] => 45 
    [5] => d
    [6] => 123
    [7] => e
    [8] => f
)
```

The current pattern matches two kind of positions, positions followed by a letter `(?=\pL)`, and positions preceded by a letter `(?<=\pL)`.

Comment: You'd better explain how that works. I know regexp pretty well and it's confusing. Also, you're missing the space after `45` in the output.

Comment: Yes, as you can see I am writing my answer, and I want to put the space with the 45.